# Why do I have to push enter twice in this react input form?

Tags: reactjs

I'm new to react and have made a basic weather app. When it initialises, it automatically uses location coordinates to populate the fields. However, I also have included an input form, allowing the user to type in a different city if they choose to do so.

I store the users search term in state. If a search term has been inputted, I would like the app to make an API call based on that term, otherwise just use the coordinates provided.

```
  //state to hold search term
  const [manualSearch, setManualSearch] = useState({
    searchTerm: ""
  })

  // function to retrieve weather data from weather api based on coordinates or search term
  function getWeather() {
    let currentWeatherRequest = ""

    //if there is a search term 
    if (manualSearch.searchTerm !== "") {
      currentWeatherRequest = `http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=${manualSearch.searchTerm}&appid=${API_KEY}&units=metric`

    } else {
      // api based on coordinates
      currentWeatherRequest = `http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=${coords.latitude}&lon=${coords.longitude}&appid=${API_KEY}&units=metric`;
    }

    fetch(currentWeatherRequest)
    ....etc
```

Here is the function to update state and refresh the search if a user inputs a town to search and presses enter

```
  // search for town manually
  function handleManualSearch(event) {
    if (event.which === 13) {
      setManualSearch({
        searchTerm: event.target.value
      })
      getWeather()
    }
  }
```

I pass this function to a component which contains the input field via props. Here is the code for the input@

```
<input id="testingthis" placeholder="Enter a new location e.g. London"  name="city" type="text" onKeyPress={(event) => props.manualSearch(event)} />
```

This all works, but only when I press enter twice. I figured it would have something to do with the fact that setState is asynchronous, so I tried adding the getWeather function as a callback like so:

```
  // search for town manually
  function handleManualSearch(event) {
    if (event.which === 13) {
      setManualSearch({
        searchTerm: event.target.value
      }, () => { getWeather()})
      
    }
  }
```

...but have the same issue with this. What am I missing? I'm fairly new to react so brief explanation would be helpful also.
thanks!

Comment: You could just pass the value from the event directly to the ```getWeatcher()``` method to skip waiting for local state to be updated. 
in your ```getWeather()``` function, what does it give you when you log ```manualSearch```?

Comment: Try to run this without callback function just: getWeather() as a second param

Comment: Thanks @szczocik, that is a much more sensible way of implementing this and it works.